# Accordion Scroll to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an scrollTo command to the following accordion code.

The problem is the slideup() command changes the screen then the position is detected wrong.

```
$handlers.removeClass('active');
$panels.slideUp();
$(this).addClass('active').parent().find('.accordion-container').slideDown();
var position = $(this).position();
window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top - 110);
```

The above code works correct if the all accordion containers are closed. If one of the containers are open and it is closed with the slideup() command then the position command fails and then the screen is moved to completely wrong position.

Full function

```
!(function($){

$.fn.Accordion = function(options){

    var settings = $.extend({
        hidefirst: 0
    }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

        var $items      = $(this).find('>div');
        var $handlers   = $items.find('.toggler');
        var $panels     = $items.find('.accordion-container');

        if( settings.hidefirst === 1 )
        {
            $panels.hide().first();
        }
        else
        {
            $handlers.first().addClass('active');
            $panels.hide().first().slideDown();
        }

        $handlers.on('click', function(){

            if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
            {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $panels.slideUp();
            }
            else
            {
                $handlers.removeClass('active');
                $panels.slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('active').parent().find('.accordion-container').slideDown();
                var position = $(this).position();
                window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top - 110);

            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: add more code for us to understand.

Comment: @andam Full function code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use callbacks for some reason, you could also add a timeout of lets say 100ms and scroll after it has completed.
That way the dom will probably be already built when the scrolling kicks in.

But I would recommend using the callback of slideDown.
It takes a function 'complete' as seen here: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

So change your code to something like this:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
var accCont = $(this).parent().find('.accordion-container');
accCont.slideDown(200, function() {
    var position = accCont.position();
    window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top - 110);
});
```

It may not be 100% correct for your use-case, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: The first edit worked I just added parent to the this command. And increased timeout to 400.
     $(this).addClass('active').parent().find('.accordion- container').slideDown(400, function() {
     var position = $(this).parent().position();
     window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top - 110);
     });